# How to delete the record based on last character of previous record in a file

Tags: shell-script, awk

How do we delete the current record based on last character of previous record and first character of current  record.

example:

```
abcd|efg
"xyz"|"ghi"
"lmn"|"qrs"
123|abc
```

requirement is to delete a record whose previous record end with double quotes and current record does not start with double quotes. In above example 4th record should be deleted from output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '(prev !~ /"$/) || ($1 ~ /^"/){print} {prev=$1}' file
abcd|efg
"xyz"|"ghi"
"lmn"|"qrs"
```

or if you prefer any of these:

```
$ awk '!( (prev ~ /"$/) && ($1 !~ /^"/) ){print} {prev=$1}' file
abcd|efg
"xyz"|"ghi"
"lmn"|"qrs"

$ awk '{f=((prev ~ /"$/) && ($1 !~ /^"/)); prev=$1} !f' file
abcd|efg
"xyz"|"ghi"
"lmn"|"qrs"
```